# If $a + b \equiv 0 \pmod p$, and $a + b \equiv 0 \pmod q$, why does $a + b \equiv 0 \pmod {pq}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Put a bit more coherently, given $p$ and $q$ as distinct prime numbers, and thus $(p,q)=1$, if

$$p^{(q-1)} + q^{(p-1)} \equiv 1 \pmod p$$
and
$$p^{(q-1)} + q^{(p-1)} \equiv 1 \pmod q,$$

why does that lead to

$$p^{(q-1)} + q^{(p-1)} \equiv 1 \pmod {pq}?$$

The textbook I'm working with jumps to that conclusion as if it were obvious, but it's not. Not to me, at least.

Comment: I think about fundamental theorem of arithmetic...

Comment: I've had lots of hints. I can manipulate the CRT over and over mechanically but have no understanding of it. When it comes to number theory, I just need someone to tell me, and then I understand, much like C.Williamson has just done. Now that he's told me, I understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question should be rephrased as:

Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct prime numbers. If $p | x$ and $q | x$, is it true that $pq | x$?

The fundamental theorem of arithmetic should answer this immediately.

Comment: It does. Many thanks, now perfectly clear.

Answer (score 1):

Since $p$ and $q$ are distinct prime numbers, if they both separately divide $a+b$, then they both occur in the prime factorization of $a+b$. Therefore, $pq$ would divide $a+b$.

Comment: Are you saying $ijpq=jp=iq$??

Comment: Let me edit my post...

Comment: Now that is the same as my answer except that my $x$ is your $a + b$.

Comment: True, and you were first. My first answer was bad.

Comment: Guys, guys, it's all for the joy of helping number theory idiots like me! Can't we all just get along? :)  Also, if I ever meet Tom Apostol, I'm going to push him over. Fair warning given.

Comment: I think we are all getting along :)

Comment: I think so too!